# Nested $Lookup to show only one value inside array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Right now I have this data:

```
db={
  "stores": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "test store"
    }
  ],
  "services": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "store": 1,
      "description": "service 1",
      "categories": [
        1,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "store": 1,
      "description": "service 2",
      "categories": [
        2
      ]
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "cat 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "cat 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "cat 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to bring all the stores, with all their services. So I did this query:

```
db.stores.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "services",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "store",
      "as": "services"
    }
  }
])
```

This works fine, the result is the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "item": "test store",
    "services": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "categories": [
          1,
          3
        ],
        "description": "service 1",
        "store": 1
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "categories": [
          2
        ],
        "description": "service 2",
        "store": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, I want a little tweak to this query. I want that the categories inside services contain the names of such categories instead of the ids, like this:

```
"categories": [
        "cat 1",
        "cat 2"
      ]
```

What change do I need to make in the query to achieve this?

This is the playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/bR3kNBnxpWY

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with this:

```
db.stores.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "services",
      // "localField": "_id",
      // "foreignField": "store",
      "let": {
        store: "$_id"
      },
      "as": "services",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$store"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "categories",
            "localField": "categories",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "categories"
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            categories: "$categories.name"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```